# Flutter row as child of container is not working

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have the following code, which works. But when I replace `Column` with `Row` in following code I get the error `Horizontal RenderFlex with multiple children has a null textDirection, so the layout order is undefined.`

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      color: Colors.red,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          Container(
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
          Container(
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),
        ],
      )
    );
  }
```

Following code generate errors.

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      color: Colors.red,
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          ...,
          ...,
          ...,
        ],
      )
    );
  }
```

Comment: Ok, but this code absolutely works fine without any error.

Comment: @Mobina If the code is inside `MaterialApp`, it works. But if used without MaterialApp, for example, when Container used as root, it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Row needs `textDirection` to be set as follows.

```
Row(
  textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
  children: [...],
)
```